# .htaccess and php - need instructions with inclusion

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, directory-tree

So this is my site structure:

- public_html

  - .htaccess
  - test-dir

    - home.php
  - includes-dir

    - file.php

And here's the code in home.php:
     require"./includes-dir/file.php"; 
But this fails. How to require file.php in home.php correctly? I need this becauase my .htaccess file redirects domain.com to domain.com/test-dir. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the dirname in PHP to get the current file location.
http://www.php.net/dirname

`require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../includes-dir/file.php';`

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be after this:

require_once dirname(**FILE**) . '/../path to file.php';